# If commits are snapshots, then why does `git stash pop` retain your changes from after the stash?

Tags: git

In my quest to understand git a little bit better, I am learning that:

1. Commits are not changes/deltas, they are snapshots
2. Stashes are commits

I had assumed for years that commits were deltas but they are actually snapshots. Got it.

Now I do this:

1. Type some text in file A
2. Stash
3. Type some text in file B
4. Commit
5. Stash pop

I am expecting that stash pop will delete the text in file B, because it is applying a snapshot of the project from before this text was added. But this is not the case, it applies the stash as if it is a delta, not a snapshot.

So what am I missing here? What does it really mean for commits to be snapshots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it applies the stash as if it is a delta, not a snapshot

Correct. It is in *itself* a snapshot, but "apply" is a form of merge and is enacted as a *diff* from the HEAD off which it was formed. The stash commit did not remove the text in file B in relation to the HEAD commit that preceded it, so applying it does not remove the text.

If you don't understand merge logic, you might want to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/. Not only merge itself but revert, cherry pick, rebase, and your "apply" all use merge logic. (This is why any of them, including applying a stash, can fail due to a merge conflict.)

Comment: Thank you @matt! Very clear now - Your blog has come up while I've been googling around, and I'm excited to read them more in depth now that I have this foundation.

Comment: Another way of seeing it is that the commit in the stash does not magically appear wholesale at the HEAD. What appears is a construct, a completely new commit effectively formed by cherry picking. The same is true of merge, revert, cherry pick, and rebase.

Comment: @matt suppse in the OP's example, both file A and file B were preexisting files before step 1. further, suppose steps 1 and 3 *appended* text to the files. Then, after step 5, would not the original status of file B be restored where the appended text is not there? If yes, then, your answer (if I am understanding it correctly) only applies to the case where file b is a new file created ni Step 3 which did not exist in prior steps. Am I right in this?

Comment: @Tryer I don't think so, but why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @matt After step 5, changes to both A in step 1 and B in step 3 are present. Let me understand why that is based on your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Tryer If you're not getting it (merge logic!), even after reading my article, feel free to ask a separate question.